# How to modify the f-test null hypothesis in ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, f-test

Normally the null hypothesis for a f-test in ANOVA is

$H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=...=\mu_m$ for a comparison of $m$ groups.

How do I alter the f-statistic so that the null hypothesis is

$H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=...=\mu_m=0$ ?

When comparing two groups with a t-test this is simple:

$t=\frac{\bar{x}-0}{SE}$

Can this be done for an f-test?